# Alphabetical sort arraylist

Tags: java

I have a string arraylist, need to sort list in alphabetical order. The logic needs to ignore lowercase versus uppercase, as well as any extra punctuation (e.g. periods, dashes).

Example:
Incorrect:
T-ext,
TABC (Text),
TE Text

Correct:
TABC (Text),
T-ext,
TE Text

Comment: create custom comparator, remove punc and set everything to upper or lower. Thats all youll get

Comment: You are trying to do something that is different from the default. Use a sort with a custom comparator. With this, you can compare two Strings and determine which is "first" in your version of ordering.

Answer (score 1):

First you iterate through your list and get rid of the character you dont want to be part of the ordering. Second you just call sort on your collection, or Collections.sort(List,Comparator) with a custom comparator.
You can also get rid of the unwanted characters in the Comparator method if you want to keep the original as it is.